# How to query XAML file with Powershell's `select-xml` commandlet?

Tags: powershell, xaml, xpath, powershell-cmdlet, select-xml

I'm trying to use the `select-xml` cmdlet in Powershell to query some XAML files in my .NET project. Here's what I've tried:

```
select-xml -content (cat $xaml_file_path) -xpath "//GroupBox"
```

Where `$xaml_file_path` is simply a string containing the file path to the XAML file of interest.

This throws an error:

> Select-Xml: Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Content'. The argument is null, empty, or an element of the argument collection contains a null value. Supply a collection that does not contain any null values and then try the command again.

I know the XAML is valid since it compiles fine on Visual Studio. So I'm thinking there might be something else going on here.

Is there a way to query XAML files using Powershell? If so how?

Comment: `Select-Xml` can read the file on its own, just pass the path to it: `Select-Xml -LiteralPath $xaml_file_path -XPath '//GroupBox'`

Comment: That doesn't work either. I just get  a null result.

Comment: By "a null result", do you mean there's no output? That'd simply mean no `<GroupBox>` elements were found in the document. Can you share the contents of the XAML file?

Comment: I cannot, but running it on http://xpather.com/ will return the desired `GroupBox` elements, so I know that it's a valid xpath query. Please see my proposed answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**To query an XML (XAML) document that uses *namespaces*, [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml) requires you to**:<sup>[1]</sup>

- ***declare* all the namespaces** that any nodes involved in your [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) query are in, via a **[hashtable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables)** that **maps *self-chosen* prefixes to namespace URIs** (parameter `-Namespace`).

  - Those self-chosen prefixes may, but needn't, be the same as in the input document, with the *exception* of the *default* namespace (`xmlns`), for which a name must be chosen too, but which can *not* be `xmlns` (the example below uses `_`).
- **use those self-chosen prefixes for *all* the nodes referenced in the XPath query** (parameter `-XPath`), including those in the *default* (implied) namespace.

A simple example:

```powershell
# Create a sample XAML file.
@"
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Test"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="500">
    <Grid>
        <TextBox x:Name="UserInnput" Height="140" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" Padding="4" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
        <Button x:Name="Save" Content="Save" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100" IsDefault="True" Height="22" Margin="170,150,0,0" />        
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@ | Set-Content sample.xml

# Create the hashtable that uses self-chosen names to the URIs
# of those namespaces involved in the XPath query below.
$namespaces = @{ 
  # This is the default namespace, which the elements in the input
  # document that have *no* namespace prefix are *implicitly* in.
  # You must NOT use 'xmlns' as the prefix.
  _ = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation'
  # For non-default namespaces, you may choose the same prefixes 
  # as in the original document.
  # Note:
  #  * This namespace isn't actually used in the query below.
  #  * However, if the nodes involved in the query do fall into
  #    this or other namespaces, they must be declared here too,
  #    and their prefixes must then be used in the query.
  x = 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml' 
}

# Query the XAML file, passing the hashtable to -Namespace, and
# using its keys as namespace prefixes; here, '_:' must be used
# to refer to nodes in the default namespace.
Select-Xml -LiteralPath sample.xml -Namespace $namespaces -XPath '//_:TextBox'
```

---

If you want to **avoid having to deal with namespaces**:

- **In the context of `Select-Xml`** (as well as the underlying [`System.Xml.XmlDocument.SelectNodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectNodes) .NET method), the only way to avoid having to deal with namespaces is to use the **`*[local-name()='...']` *workaround*** shown in [your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74180818/45375).
- **In the context of [PowerShell's adaption of the `[xml]` DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49213568/45375)**, which adds "virtual" *properties* to instances of `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)):

  - These properties are *always* named for the *non-prefixed* node names; that is, namespaces are effectively *ignored*.
  - This is convenient and often sufficient, but it **limits you to "drilling down" with *dot notation*** into the document, as opposed to having being able to run XPath *queries* against the document; for the latter, you can use the `.SelectNodes()` and `.SelectSingleNode()` *methods*, which, however, again necessitate namespace management.<sup>[1]</sup>
  - The equivalent example with dot notation, building on the same sample file:

    ```powershell
    # Parse the XML file into an [xml] instance.
    ($doc = [xml]::new()).Load((Convert-Path sample.xml))

    # Drill down to the <TextBox> element.
    # Note: If the <Grid> element had *multiple* <TextBox> children,
    #       they would *all* be returned, as a System.Xml.XmlElement array.
    $doc.Window.Grid.TextBox
    ```

---

<sup>[1] The need for namespace management applies analogously to direct use of the underlying [`System.Xml.XmlDocument.SelectNodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectNodes) and [`System.Xml.XmlDocument.SelectSingleNodes()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlNode.SelectSingleNode) .NET API, although constructing the prefix-to-URI mapping table is a little more cumbersome there - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51379117/45375).</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I think that, similarly to `xmllint` there might be an [issue](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/56822/how-do-i-parse-namespaces-from-an-xml-file-using-xmllint-and-bash) with handling namespaces.

I've found that the following does work:

```
(select-xml -path $xaml_file_path -xpath "//*[local-name()='GroupBox']").Node
```

If anyone knows of a cleaner/better way to do this (i.e. using the `-namespace` flag), I would be curious to hear about it.