# How can I list possible XPath queries for an XML object in PowerShell?

Tags: xml, powershell, xpath

How can I get the list of possible XPath queries for an xml object in PowerShell?

Comment: Please supply a [mcve]. (if you just type '$xml' PowerShell should show you the root property. Anyways, it is probably easier to use PowerShell XML dot notation)

Comment: Please show a sample XML document

Comment: The list of *possible* queries is infinite; XPath is a pretty flexible language that is not restricted to just querying by element name. As Ron mentions, autocomplete with dot notation is a very convenient way of exploring the data. As a bonus, this disregards namespaces, while XPath is very much respectful of them: `([xml]'<x xmlns="urn:mystuff">a</x>')|select-xml "/x"` will yield nothing, unlike `([xml]'<x xmlns="urn:mystuff">a</x>').x`.

Comment: @iRon I skipped the rss tag while reading the xml file, that was the problem. Still, my question is about the listing of possible XML paths

Comment: All (recursive) XML paths??? or at a certain level (e.g. `$xml.rss`). *My* question (to be able to better help you) is still: please supply a [mcve].

Comment: You'll still have to narrow down your question to what it really is you're after; as it stands it's unanswerable. Any node can be selected by very many queries that end up referring to the same node ("the third element", "the first non-empty element", "the first element that has a child named Bob" and "the element named Alice" are all expressible in XPath and could all be the same element). If you just want to visualize the XML document's structure I suggest writing it to a file and using one of the many XML editors out there (or even just your browser).

Answer (score 1):

As the comments note, it is **impossible to list all possible [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath) *queries*** for a given XML document, given the complexity of this open-ended query language, with different ways to target the same nodes, ...

However, **it is possible and may be useful to output XPath *path expressions* to the *leaf* elements of a document**, so as **to get a sense of the document structure**, and to be able to formulate XPath queries based on them.

Assuming that helper function `Get-XmlElementPath` is defined (source code below), you can do something the following:

```bash
# Sample XML doc.
$xmlDocText = @'
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <catalog>
        <book id="bk101">
            <title>De Profundis</title>
        </book>
        <book id="bk102">
            <title>Pygmalion</title>
        </book>
    </catalog>
    <foo>
        <bar>one</bar>
        <bar>two</bar>
    </foo>
</doc>
'@

Get-XmlElementPath $xmlDocText
```

This outputs the following strings, representing the XPath path expressions that select the document's leaf elements:

```
/doc/catalog/book[@id="bk101"]/title
/doc/catalog/book[@id="bk102"]/title
/doc/foo/bar[1]
/doc/foo/bar[2]
```

**Note**:

- **Caveat**: The function does *not* (fully) support *namespaces* - while elements with *explicit* namespace prefixes are reported as such, those *implicitly* in a namespace are reported by their name only; if the input document uses namespaces and you want to query it based on the path expressions returned, you'll need to:

  - Create a namespace manager with self-chosen prefixes to refer to the namespace URIs, including the default one.
  - Use these prefixes in the XPath path expression, even for elements that are in the *default* namespace.
  - The following answers demonstrate these techniques:

    - In the context of the `.SelectNodes()` and `.SelectSingleNode()` .NET API methods: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74181458/45375).
    - In the context of the [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml) cmdlet: see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027077/45375).
- Only *element* nodes are considered, and only *leaf* elements, i.e. those elements that themselves do not have any element children.
- If a given child element has an `"id"` or `"name"` attribute, its path is
  represented with an XPath conditional (`[@id="..."]` or `[@name="..."]`; `"id"` takes precedence), under the assumption that these values are *unique* (at least among the sibling elements).
- Multiple child elements with the same name that do not have `"id"` or `"name"` attributes are each represented by their 1-based positional index (e.g, `[1]`).

---

**`Get-XmlElementPath` source code**; run `Get-XmlElementPath -?` for help:

```bash
function Get-XmlElementPath {
  <#
  .SYNOPSIS
  Outputs XPath paths for all leaf elements of a given XML document.
  
  .DESCRIPTION
  Leaf elements are those XML elements that have no element children.
  
  If a given child element has an "id" or "name" attribute, its path is 
  represented with an XPath conditional ([@id="..."] or [@name="..."])

  Multiple child elements with the same name that do not have "id" or "name" 
  attributes are each represented by their 1-based positional index.
  
  Note: Namespaces are NOT (fully) supported: while elements with
        explicit namespace prefixes are reported as such, those
        that are implicitly in a namespace are reported by name only.
  
  .EXAMPLE
  Get-XmlElementPath '<catalog><book id="bk101">De Profundis</book><book id="bk102">Pygmalion</book></catalog>'
  
  /catalog/book[@id="bk101"]
  /catalog/book[@id="bk102"]
  #>

  param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory)] $Xml,            # string, [xml] instance, or [XmlElement] instance
    [Parameter(DontShow)] [string] $Prefix, # used internally
    [Parameter(DontShow)] [string] $Index   # used internally
  )

  if ($Xml -is [string]) {
    $Xml = [xml] $Xml
  }
  if ($Xml -is [xml]) { $Xml = $Xml.DocumentElement}

  # Construct this element's path.
  $Prefix += '/' + $Xml.psbase.Name # !! .psbase.Name must be used to guard againts a "name" *attribute* preempting the type-native property.
  if ($Index) { $Prefix += '[{0}]' -f $Index }

  $childElems = $Xml.ChildNodes.Where({ $_ -is [System.Xml.XmlElement]})
  if ($childElems) {
    # Create a hashtable that maps child element names to how often they occur.
    $htNames = [hashtable]::new() # Note: case-*sensitive*, because XML is.
    foreach ($name in $childElems.get_Name()) { $htNames[$name]++ }
    # Create a hashtable that maintains the per-name count so far in the iteration.
    $htIndices = [hashtable]::new() 
    # Iterate over all child elements and recurse.
    foreach ($child in $childElems) {
      $Index = ''
      if ($htNames[$child.psbase.Name] -gt 1) { $Index = ++$htIndices[$child.psbase.Name] }
      # If an 'id' attribute is present, use it instead of a positional index.
      if ($id = $child.GetAttribute('id')) { $Index = '@id="{0}"' -f $id }
      elseif ($id = $child.GetAttribute('name')) { $Index = '@name="{0}"' -f $id }
      # Recurse
      Get-XmlElementPath $child $Prefix $Index
    }
  } else { # leaf element reached
    $Prefix # output the path
  }

}
```