# Producing an element with a namespace, but no prefix on the element name using [Xml.XmlWriter]::WriteStartElement()

Tags: xml, powershell, .net-core

I am trying to reproduce the following line from an SQL Server .regsrvr file. It does not include the prefix on the element name, 'definitions'.

```
<definitions xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08">
```

If I use the three (3) parameter version of WriteStartElement()

```
$xmlw.WriteStartElement('sfc', 'definitions', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08')
```

it produces the prefix on the element name.

```
<sfc:definitions xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" />
```

If I use the two (2) parameter version of WriteStartElement()

```
$xmlw.WriteStartElement('definitions', 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08')
```

it does not include the prefix 'sfc'.

```
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" />
```

Does it matter if the prefix is present on the element name?

```
PS C:\> $PSVersionTable.PSVersion.ToString()
7.2.7
```

**Update:**

@mklement0 - is this correct?

This is from the .regsrvr created by SSMS. The `definitions` element creates `sfc` as the "default" namespace for descendent elements. The `document`, `docinfo`, and `aliases` elements are considered part of the `sfc` namespace.

If the `definitions` element was given as `sfc:definitions`, then the descendent elements would be considered as part of the parent `xs` namespace.

If `sfc` became the namespace for descendents of `definitions`, does `sfc:version` need to have the `sfc` prefix?

```
<xs:bufferSchema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <definitions xmlns:sfc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08">
    <document>
      <docinfo>
        <aliases>
          <alias>/system/schema/RegisteredServers</alias>
        </aliases>
        <sfc:version DomainVersion="1" />
      </docinfo>
      <data>
```

Comment: I only saw your update now (@-mentioning users in the _body_ of a post never results in a notification). No, the descendants would _not_ be considered part of the parent `xs` namespace, given that that namespace is defined with an _explicit prefix_ - only those descendants that use `<xs:…>` explicitly would be in that namespace. So if you changed `<definitions xmlns:sfc=…>` to `<sfc:definitions xmlns:sfc=…>`, the same would apply there: only `<sfc:…>` descendants would be in that namespace - you've effectively only changed the namespace for `<definitions>` itself.

Comment: So it sounds like you were looking for `<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08" />` after all, which puts `<definitions>` and all its descendants into that namespace by default.

Answer (score 0):

> Does it matter if the prefix is present on the element name?

**It doesn't matter for the element *itself***, because in both cases the element is considered to be in the `http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/sfc/serialization/2007/08` namespace, **but it has implications for *descendant* elements**:

- `<definitions xmlns="http://..." />` puts not only the element at hand in that namespace, but also **makes that namespace the implied *default* namespace for descendant elements** that do no that themselves declare a new namespace.

  - That is, *descendant* elements that also do *not* use a *namespace prefix* and also do not use `xmlns='...'` (to declare a *new* default namespace for all descendants) are implicitly considered to be in the same namespace.
- `<sfc:definitions xmlns:sfc="http://..." />` puts the element in that namespace **by explicit prefix** (`sfc:`).

  - This means that ***descendant* elements too need to use the same prefix in order to be considered part of the same namespace**.
  - Otherwise, elements that do not themselves declare a new (default) namespace are considered to be in any *higher-up* element's default namespace or, if there is none, in no namespace at all.

The following simplified example demonstrates this:

```bash
# Sample input XML
[xml] $xml = @'
<xml>
    <sfc:definitions id="1" xmlns:sfc="http://example.org/def1">
        <sfc:explicit>hi1</sfc:explicit>
    </sfc:definitions>
    <definitions id="2" xmlns="http://example.org/def2">
        <implicit>hi2</implicit>
    </definitions>    
</xml>
'@

# Loop over all <definitions> child elements and report
# their respect child element's effective namespace URI
$xml.xml.definitions | % {
  $_.ChildNodes | % {
    [PSCustomObject]@{
      Child = $_.OuterXml
      Namespace = $_.NamespaceUri
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```bash
Child                                                                Namespace
-----                                                                ---------
<sfc:explicit xmlns:sfc="http://example.org/def1">hi1</sfc:explicit> http://example.org/def1
<implicit xmlns="http://example.org/def2">hi2</implicit>             http://example.org/def2
```

---

However, the **first element quoted in your question, from your SQL Server `.regsrvr` file can *not* be written as such with a single `.WriteStartElement()` call**, because it combines an *un-prefixed* name with defining a namespace *with prefix*, whereas the [`WriteStartElement()` overloads](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writestartelement) offer only the following variations:

- create an *un-prefixed* element name *without* a namespace attribute (e.g. `<definitions>`),
- create an *un-prefixed* name with a *default* namespace attribute (e.g. `<definitions xmlns="...">`); however, if the namespace URI was used in a prefix declaration in an *ancestral* element, say with prefix `foo`, you'll get `<foo:definitions>` instead.
- create a *prefixed* element name with a namespace attribute *with prefix* (e.g. `<sfc:definitions xmlns:sfc="...">`)

The **workaround** is to *manually* create the `xmlns:sfc` attribute, using **[`WriteAttributeString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.xml.xmlwriter.writeattributestring)**; here's a self-contained example:

```bash
$sb = [System.Text.StringBuilder]::new()
$writer = [System.XML.XmlWriter]::Create($sb)

$writer.WriteStartElement('definitions')
$writer.WriteAttributeString('xmlns', 'sfc', $null, 'http://example.org')
$writer.WriteEndElement()

$writer.Dispose()

# Output the completed documented as a string.
($xmlText = $sb.ToString())
```

Result:

```bash
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?><definitions xmlns:sfc="http://example.org" />
```

Note the *un-prefixed* element name, `definitions`, combined with the namespace attribute that *declares a prefix*, `xmlns:sfc="..."`.
This element is therefore itself *not* in that namespace.

---

**Implications of the presence of namespaces for element access / queries:**

- [PowerShell's adaptation of the XML DOM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027077/45375) using ***dot notation***, as shown above, ***ignores* namespaces**, meaning that **only the (prefix-less) element *names* matter**, irrespective of what namespace they're in (whether it be by default or with an explicit prefix).
- By contrast, **using [XPath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath)** to query `[xml]` ([`System.Xml.XmlDocument`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Xml.XmlDocument)) instances **requires *explicit namespace handling***:

  - For using XPath queries with the [`Select-Xml`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-xml) cmdlet, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74181458/45375).
  - For using XPath queries with the `[xml]` .NET type's `.SelectNodes()` and `.SelectSingleNodes()` methods, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73027077/45375).

Comment: thank you for your detailed and very helpful answer. It contains a lot of good information. Is it possible to use `WriteStartElement()` to produce the `definitions` element without the prefix on the element name?

Comment: Glad to hear it, @lit. If you use the _single-parameter_ `WriteStartElement()` overload, you should get an un-prefixed element name (and no `xmlns` attribute); i.e., in your case, `.WriteStartElement('definitions')`

Comment: I have also tried the _single-parameter_ overload, but it does not include any URI. My goal is to reproduce the original .regsrvr file line, so I am not there yet. I have not spent the time needed to see if also having the prefix on the element name (unlike the .regsrvr file) causes any difference when SSMS reads it.

Comment: @lit, good point: it _would_ make a difference, because the original element combines an _unprefixed_ element name with an namespace attribute _with prefix_, which `.WriteStartElement()` cannot directly produce; please see my update for a solution.